# Error generating c# proxy with svcutil

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I am trying to generate C# proxy class for web service from WSDL file using svcutil. Svcutil returns following errors:

1. Error: Style Document on header authHeader does not match expected style Rpc.
2. For every method in service there is additional error message:
   "Error: Extensions for operation 'methodName' in binding CBS cannot specify different values."

I have tried to access service using soapUI and same WSDL file and it works without a problem.

I have no control over service and no direct communication with team that develops it.

This is link to [WSDL](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=723AAE119EAA0616&id=723AAE119EAA0616%21159).

Comment: Is the wsdl public?  E.G. could you provide a link to it?

Comment: Since the WSDL is not public, can you at least share what exact parameters you gave to svcutil.exe when you attempted to generate the code?

Comment: I added WSDL, check the link at the end of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of discussions with developers that created the service, we concluded that there are some compatibility problems between .NET and Java.

Service developers made several changes on their side and at one moment, it started working on my side.